# Sort data from FireBase by 2 keys

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I built game app and I save records on real time database of FireBase.
the database look:

```
{
    "Ka8xxTgyFB8yYKH50j" : {
        "score" : 10,
        "seconds" : 1325
    },
    "K222xTgyFBF33FD50j" : {
        "score" : 10,
        "seconds" : 425
    },
    "Ka32T23R328yYKH50j" : {
        "score" : 5,
        "seconds" : 115
    },
    "F323F32FB8yYKH50j" : {
        "score" : 30,
        "seconds" : 2335
    }
    }
}
```

I want to get the data from FireBase sorted by score, and then sort by seconds.
the right order of the data in this example should to be:

score:5 seconds:115

score:10 seconds:425

score:10 seconds:1325

score:30 seconds:2335

How can I do this using orderByChild ot other way?
thank you

Comment: Firebase rt db (as you know) does not allow sorting by more than one field, so chances are you'll have to do client side ordering. If your data set is small enough it shouldn't be a problem, even thousands of rows should be ok unless you're doing this a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Since firebase does not allow multi-sort, I recommend you to create a sort column and update it according to your sorting requirement. 
In your case, you can concatenate the seconds and score, then store it as integer. To give it consistent length, seconds must be str padded with 0 for lets say 6 chars (depends on your score and seconds max possible values). 
Lets say, maximum score is 100, and max seconds are 50000, your sort order would be combination of `score` and `5 chars of seconds`, casted as integer.

Example:

```
{
    "Ka8xxTgyFB8yYKH50j" : {
        "score" : 10,
        "seconds" : 1325,
        "sort_order": 1001325
    },
    "K222xTgyFBF33FD50j" : {
        "score" : 10,
        "seconds" : 425,
        "sort_order": 1000425
    },
    "Ka32T23R328yYKH50j" : {
        "score" : 5,
        "seconds" : 115
        "sort_order": 5000115
    },
    "F323F32FB8yYKH50j" : {
        "score" : 30,
        "seconds" : 2335,
        "sort_order": 3002335
    }
}
```

This way, you can sort it very fast in both ascending and descending orders.

Comment: This is a cool concept, never thought about concatenating orders in firebase. Although if doing too many of these tricks then possibly firebase is being stretched to its limits and should look into a different db technology.

Comment: @AndresS This is actually preferred way of storing things in firebase-like dbs because it encourages denormalization. Tbh, even in sql rdbms you would do it to get best possible performance depending on table schemas. Sorting by multi column means lots of memory + lots of cpu.

Comment: Sure but at some point you're trading readability/maintainability for what could potentially not be significant resource usage. In super mega optimization mode I could see it being a benefit in many places but the question always stands "is this necessary?" (In this case I'd argue yes it is because of limitations)

Comment: Of course it depends on the application and database software, but firebase is a very feature limited and meant to be real-time database, which means low latency is crucial. In this case, adding one more column to gain 10ms would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. 
First sort data while you are uploading.

```
databaseReference.**orderByValue("score")**.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }

                        });
```

After this, sort again while fetching the data

```
    setmFirebaseAdapter1(new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<taskdata, wealth.ShowDataViewHolder>(
                taskdata.class, R.layout.budget_rv_layout, wealth.ShowDataViewHolder.class,retrieceds.**orderByChild(seconds)**) {
            public void populateViewHolder(final wealth.ShowDataViewHolder viewHolder, final taskdata model, final int position) {
})
```